# ColdFusion Lucee Or Railo RestFull Webservice Mapping issue

Tags: web-services, rest, coldfusion, railo, lucee

Creating my first RestFul Webservice on ColdFusion Lucee.

These are the steps which I followed.

1. Created folder on ROOT Named "RestAPI"
2. Created sub-Folder under RestAPI/API (For CFC)
3. Created CFC RestAPI/API/Hello.cfc

Hello.cfc

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/hello"> 
    <cffunction name="formPost" access="remote" returnType="String" httpMethod="POST" restPath="/form">
        <cfargument name="firstname" type="String" restArgSource="Form">
        <cfargument name="lastname" type="String" restArgSource="Form">
        <cfset res="firstname : " & #firstname# & " lastname : " & #lastname#>
        <cfreturn res>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

4. Created CFM Call.cfm

Call.cfm

```
<cfhttp url="http://mydev:8888/rest/Example/hello/form" method="POST" result="res" port="8888">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="firstname" value="Dan">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="lastname" value="Bin">
```

5. Created a mapping in lucee admin server. `/Example`

When I run the Call.cfm I am getting this output

> no rest service for [/RestAPI/call.cfm] found in mapping [/Example]

[Please see the attached screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWqob.png)

[Just want to know why it is not working in root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1b1b.png)

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you have placed your `call.cfm` template within the RestAPI path `mydev:8888/rest/RestAPI/call.cfm`. Move it to the webroot and try again `mydev:8888/call.cfm`.

Comment: @Miguel-F thanks for response .. im keeping RestAPI/call.cfm and API im keeping in sub-folder of  RestAPI. i can't keepin root folder of API??

Comment: I am only referring to the `call.cfm` file where you are calling your Rest service. Put only that file in the webroot. Then call it from your browser `mydev:8888/call.cfm`. All of your cfc's remain under `RestAPI`.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I think I see what you mean now. So instead try calling it as `mydev:8888/RestAPI/call.cfm`. Do not include `/rest` in your call to the CFM but do include `/rest` when calling your service.

Comment: @Miguel-F yes it is working of side the root folder, actually it is working everywhere except RestAPI folder. i was trying understand why is that so?? although im not keeping my file in component folder in my case it is "API".

Comment: @Miguel-F one last question please answer in answer box.  i can keep multiple component (cfcs) files in one folder  & map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your initial screenshot I found that the issue seems to be how you are calling your `call.cfm` template. The error message being reported is:

> no rest service for [/RestAPI/call.cfm] found in mapping [/Example]

That tells me that it is looking for a service through your REST API instead of simply calling the template. I think this is because you referenced your `call.cfm` template using `/rest/` in the URL. Again from the screenshot I saw this in your browser's address bar:

```
mydev:8888/rest/RestAPI/call.cfm
```

This is when I suggested moving your `call.cfm` template out of that sub-folder and into the web root.  However, I think it will also work if you reference it correctly when the `call.cfm` file is contained in your `/RestAPI/` folder. You should be able to reference it like so:

```
mydev:8888/RestAPI/call.cfm
```

Notice that I have removed the `/rest/` reference from this URL for the browser request. You do still need the `/rest/` reference within your `<cfhttp>` call though.

*one last question please answer in answer box. i can keep multiple component (cfcs) files in one folder & map?*

Yes you can keep multiple CFCs within your API folder.